# How to derive the lifetime of proton $p$ in $SU(5)$ theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, proton-decay

In particular in $SU(3)\times{}SU(2)\times{}U(1)$ theory the proton is stable. But in $SU(5)$ it is not. What makes the difference and how do you calculate it?

I am hoping for an overview to give me an intuition for what is going on here.

Comment: Have you learned how to calculate the decay rate of other unstable particles such as muons?

Comment: @G.Smith   No, I am assuming that the principle is identical. (Am I right)? Somehow, I am just not groking the process other than as a rather intractable idea in non-linear field theory.

Comment: I haven’t seen the calculation of the proton decay rate in, say, an $SU(5)$ GUT, but I think it is probably very similar to calculating other decay rates in QED or the Standard Model. The standard formula is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_decay#Decay_rate). Some relevant Feynman diagrams are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay).

Comment: Perhaps I should add that I get the idea of listing the way that the muon can decay and working out the transfer rate from linear mode to linear mode, and as a Poisson process that gives the half-life. What I am missing is how do you get to that point. It feels like a recipe rather than a reason. I wanted to see it from the field theory.

Comment: I don’t think it is too conceptually different from scattering. You have an initial state, a final state, and a transition amplitude between them, the square of whose complex magnitude is the transition probability.

Comment: Okay. Maybe just articulating it made a lot of difference to me. I will chase up those links and cogitate.

Comment: Cool. Actually, put that as an answer and I will vote for it. My core purpose in asking this question was to find out what the straight forward (orthodox?) approach was. I think now that you have answered that for me. The rest is me doing the reading and some practice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven’t seen the calculation of the proton decay rate in, say, an $SU(5)$ GUT, but I think it is probably very similar to calculating other decay rates in QED or the Standard Model. The standard formula is based on [Fermi’s “Golden Rule”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) for transition rates. Its application to particle decays is covered [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_decay#Decay_rate). Some possible Feynman diagrams for proton decay in baryon-number-violating theories beyond the Standard Model are shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay).

Particle decays are not too conceptually different from scattering. You have an initial state, a final state, and a transition amplitude between them, the square of whose complex magnitude is the transition probability.